# What is the difference between shuffle in fit_generator and shuffle in flow_from_directory?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am using Keras to create a deep learning model and I would like to know that what is the difference between `shuffle` argument in `fit_generator()` method and `shuffle` argument in `flow_from_directory()` method?

Answer (score 1):

From `fit_generator()` documentation:

> **shuffle:** Boolean. Whether to shuffle the order of the batches at the beginning of each epoch. Only used with instances of `Sequence`
>   (`keras.utils.Sequence`). Has no effect when `steps_per_epoch` is not
>   `None`.

So if you are using a generator and set `steps_per_epoch` it would have no effect. In case of using a `Sequence` generator, it would get the batches in different order at each epoch. For example, in first epoch it might get `my_seq[0]` and then `my_seq[1]` and then `my_seq[2]` (and so on) and in the second epoch it might get `my_seq[2]` and then `my_seq[0]` and then `my_seq[1]` and so on for the next epochs (i.e. note that `my_seq[i]` is the i-th batch generated by the `Sequence` generator we have defined).

From `flow_from_directory()` documentation:

> **shuffle**: Whether to shuffle the data (default: `True`)

It is not clear when and how shuffling is done. So we must take a look at the source code. By doing so, we find out that `flow_from_directory()` method [returns](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/b15497b20f0e4ed4ee1883dae15a94312a5b1dff/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L1021) an instance of [`DirectoryIterator`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/b15497b20f0e4ed4ee1883dae15a94312a5b1dff/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L1811) class which in its docstring we can see the following:

> shuffle: Boolean, whether to shuffle the data between epochs.

So it would shuffle all of the data (i.e. list of all the training images to be read at each epoch) at the beginning of each epoch.